# Is there a way to query the google wallet in app payments api for the cost of a transaction?

Tags: android-pay

Is there a way to query the google wallet in app payments api for the cost of a transaction? It used to be sent with google checkout callbacks but seems to be missing for the wallet callbacks.

Edit, the details of what's included in the postback can be seen at https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no "query API" for it at this time.

However, **if** you are referring to the *fees charged by Google per transaction*, you can determine it based on the simplified [fee structure](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/faq#faq-payments-01)

Comment: Hi EdSF. Thanks for your response. I was just hoping for a non-hacky way of getting the price per transaction. If GW decide to increase or decrease the transaction fee in 6 months I'd prefer not to have to dig through code to ensure it's accounted for. If there were something like Checkout's callback which included the cost of the transaction, that'd be ideal.

Comment: @user714852 Yup, it was one of those questions I asked the Google Team at a [recent Developers Live session](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/505515436), regarding GCO API retirement - re: perhaps some of it can be re-purposed for other payment APIs that don't have such features (querying, etc).